# iOS 5/Lion Core Data ordered relationships: specify order?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am trying to use Core Data and it's ordered relationships feature, and I just can't find how would I actually specify ordering. I marked my relationship as 'ordered', but don't see where I set, say, 'order by attribute XXX descending'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ordered relationship only means that ordered in a arbitrary manner. (Ordered by the user for example.)

If you want to have an order related to your attributes, add a sort descriptor to your fetch request :

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSArray* sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: So you're saying that setting this 'ordered' flag makes CoreData generate NSOrderedSet property for managed object, and maintain it's order across different contexts? Did I get it right?

Comment: The order is maintain across launches (it's persistent on disk) with an NSOrderedSet, yes. With NSSortDescriptor it's sorted at fetch time.

Comment: @gcamp how to get this ordered set? Only to fetch "main" entity and use it's relationship property? There is no way to get "secondary" entity and sort it according to it's "main" ordered relationship, right?